# Adjective that means "snake-like"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, analogy

If *bovine* means related to the cow or ox, what is the word that means related to the snake?

Comment: An important area of clarity: Do you want a word that means "snake-like", the way that *bovine* can mean "cow-like"? (In which case mplungjan's suggestion of *serpentine* is probably the word that would be most commonly understood.)  Or do you want a word that means "related to the snake" in a more general sense, the way you can talk about "bovine diseases", "bovine anatomy", or "bovine behaviour" for topics related to cattle? You can't substitute *serpentine* in any of these cases.

Comment: And of course "snake-like" *is* an adjective that means "snake-like".

Comment: I'm not altogether sure I agree with @AmeliaBR.  I think serpentine can absolutely be used in the ways she's suggesting it cannot.  "That snake caught a serpentine disease."  (He caught a disease that only snakes can get.)

Serpentine doesn't just refer to how a snake looks.  I'm not sure where people are getting that idea.  It simply means "having characteristics of, or similarities to a snake", nothing more, nothing less.  It's literally no different than "bovine" other than it refers to snakes rather than cattle.

Comment: @JoeRounceville: Do you have examples of that usage?  I can't find "serpentine" in google scholar in any sense that refers to the study of snakes, except for a studies of "serpentine motion" (e.g., snake-like movement in robots).

Comment: @AmeliaBR:  I'm not sure I follow you.  The study of snakes is called "ophiology."  That has nothing to do with the uses of the adjective "serpentine".  Google Scholar doesn't represent all collected knowledge about the English language, and the OP didn't ask anything about scholarly works.  However, since you brought it up, here's an example:  http://www.jwildlifedis.org/doi/pdf/10.7589/0090-3558-2.4.111

This article speaks of "serpentine hosts" (snakes carrying a disease).  "Serpentine" means "snake-like" because the suffix -ine means "like", and obviously "serpent" means "snake."

Comment: @JoeRounceville  Google scholar was just an example of a database where one might expect to find articles *about* snakes and topics related to snakes, rather than (literal or metaphorical) descriptions of other things that are snake-like.  The example you found certainly meets the criteria I was looking for. I would still say that *serpentine* **usually** refers to a non-snake that has snake-like attributes, rather than to a property of snakes themselves.  But perhaps the definition should be expanded, since none of the alternatives are easily recognizable by non-specialists!

Answer (score 65):

[Serpentine](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpentine) is the snake equivalent of bovine.

> of or resembling a serpent (as in form or movement)

<sub>Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serpentine</sub>

**Serpent** - synonym of snake

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake#Taxonomy) :

> Snakes are elongated, legless, carnivorous reptiles of the suborder Serpentes
>   ...
>   All modern snakes are grouped within the suborder Serpentes in Linnean taxonomy,

Whereas [Ophidia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ophidia) is a supergroup of lizards and snakes.

> Ophidia is a group of squamate reptiles including modern snakes and all snake-like "lizards" closer to snakes than to other living groups of lizards.

I would however likely use **reptilian** or **snake-like** for descriptions of behaviour, viz *her bovine eyes looked calmly at me*

Comment: To be pedantic, 'serpentine' means '_like_ a snake' and is usually used to describe a very wavy wall or road or river. So a 'serpentine rash' would more likely evoke the idea of a rash that is wavy rather than a rash that snakes get.

Comment: Yes, and bovine means "cow-like" - _a bovine look_ means dumb with big eyes...

Comment: Yes, bovine can mean 'look or acting cow like' but the primary meaning of 'serpentine' is 'wavy'. EG "That man has a serpentine air about him" is confusing because in context it does sound like the man is personality like a snake (sneaky, beady eyed, reptilian) but the strongest connotation is that his personality is wavy _shaped_ which is incongruous.

Comment: Sinuous is marked as a synonym of serpentine in Wiktionary, and it's the first word that i thought of to describe a snake, it's used particularly the regarding a snake's behavior. Snake-like movement is sinuous, and any object that moves like a snake can be said to be sinuous.

Comment: Sinuous is the winding, not the being snakelike. I however expect the behavior of a snake to be reptilian as posted elsewhere.

Comment: There's not a great deal of room for debate here. Some of the words in other answers are very useful in themselves, but in the context of the question, "serpentine" is the actual answer.

Comment: @Mitch Serpentine can mean "like a snake" in many senses, not just wavy.  I don't see anything wrong with using *serpentine* to describe someone's character as being similar to a snake's (or at least, similar to negative stereotypes about snake behaviour).

Comment: Here's a pretty exhaustive list of adjectives for other animals, as well: http://www.davekoelle.com/animal_terms.html The author pulled the words from multiple sources, so there is no info about past usage there, but it's still a nice list.

Comment: I disagree with @Mitch... and now I'm a little confused by AmeliaBR's response, because she seems to be arguing against herself in the post above. Anyway, let it be known that most animals have an adjective that encapsulates their characteristics, usually based on the Latin word for that animal (or their most obvious characteristic). In English we started creating compound hyphenated adjectives by adding -like (cow-like, bird-like, snake-like, etc.), which is probably indicative of the gradual decline of Latin knowledge in English speaking countries.

Answer (score 22):

[Phrontistery](http://phrontistery.info/o.html) has a list of suitable words:

> **ophic**  of, like or pertaining to serpents
>   **ophidian**    of or like a snake
>   **ophiomormous**    snakelike
>   **ophiomorphic**    shaped like a snake

OED has **ophiomorphic** *Having or resembling the form of a serpent; snakelike,* and gives its etymology as deriving from ancient Greek ὄϕις *serpent*

Comment: Except who uses that word and how much does it resemble bovine compared to serpentine?

Comment: @mplungjan I merely answered the question. I'm not responsible for voting on the answer. One could always coin *ophidine* or *ophisine*.

Comment: Ophidia is a group of squamate reptiles **including** modern snakes and all snake-like "lizards" closer to snakes than to other living groups of lizards.

Comment: Again, the fact that a class is named after the Greek word ὄϕις doesn't alter the link between ὄϕις *serpent* and *ophiomorphic* "snake-like".

Comment: I have used the word "ophidian" this year in conversation.

Comment: I need to find a good context to use _ophiomormous_. It's just a cool-sounding word.

Answer (score 17):

A word derived from the Latin for snake, *anguis,* is ***anguiform.***

> Having the shape of a serpent or snake; snake-shaped.
>
> [OED]

A word which resembles *bovine* is ***anguine***.

> Of or resembling a snake or serpent.
>
> [OED]

Comment: [Anguilla](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anguilla) is an EEL!

Comment: @mplungjan Oops. Finger-memory. Thanks.

Comment: @mplungjan And "anguilliform" means "eel-like", presumably because eels look a bit like snakes.

Comment: Technically speaking "-form" means "having the outward shape and characteristics of -------".  It's not exactly the same as -like, since -like implies more than just form.

Answer (score 8):

My humble Pocket Oxford Dictionary says simply: ***snaky***.  If you want to describe someone in a negative way, perhaps *treacherous* would do the trick.

Comment: I think a lot depends on the context. If I were writing a thesis, I wouldn't use "snaky" because it sounds a little childish. However, if I were writing a fairy tale, I might.

Answer (score 7):

Reptilian wasn't mentioned. Serpentine is good but doesn't have the negative connotation.

Comment: Negative connotations like bovine has ? - Reptiles are also crocs and turtles

Comment: No. Bovine rings up the quaint environment of a rural pasture... Pretty neutral

Comment: I know, hence the question. I did not see the need for negative connotations :)

Comment: Sometimes if you want to describe a person as an animal you might want to be positive or negative about it... "The reptilian part of him took over" "he lithely snaked his way up the mountain painting a serpentine trail from above"... Connotation can change according to sentence too..

Comment: Serpentine most certainly can have a negative connotation; don't forget that the great villain of the world's most popular creation myth is a serpent.

Comment: Haha well said!

Comment: I would agree that a snake's behavior would be reptilian.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn’t expect the average unstudied English monoglot to know the word, but the OED gives as the primary sense of the adjective ***colubrine***:

> 1. Of, belonging to, or characteristic of a snake or serpent; snake-like.

One citation for that sense is:

> - 1883 P. Robinson in *Harper’s Mag.* Oct. 708/1 
>   The **colubrine** impossibility of springing off the ground at me.

A herpetologist might argue that this term more properly applies only to the Colubridae family of snakes.  Perhaps so, but only in herpetology, where a *colubrine* is also used substantively. This leads to the OED’s second sense for that word:

> 2. *Zool*. Of the nature of the Coluber or snake: applied to serpents, sometimes distinguished as ***true colubrine*** and ***venomous colubrine*** snakes.

In non-specialist use, *colubrine* is a more general term than that, one simply meaning “snaky” (itself a fine word), as the provided citation above illustrates. The word is of ancient pedigree, coming to us from Latin *colubrinus* for snake, and having cognates in neighboring languages, like Spanish *culebra*.

There are also specialized terms for other snake families, like *viperine* for viperish, *pythonic* for pythonlike, and *elapine* for sea-snakes.

Comment: 'viperine' is less opaque and is more metaphorical out of context (sneaky or treacherous) like 'reptilian' is unfeeling or reactive.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best adjective is "snakelike" as used by Jack London

'The huge, snakelike body coiled and uncoiled about its prey.'

or

"He received no applause, and he squirmed through the ropes, snakelike, into the arms of his seconds"

Answer (score 0):

The formal Greek word for snake-like is ophioides, a compound of ophis and eidos (form). In English this becomes ophioid, similarly to words like asteroid, sigmoid (sigma-like or S-like) etc.

Comment: Ophidian was already posted. Ophidia is the supergroup of lizards and snakes and no-one use that in daily speach, whereas the word serpent has been used for snakes since the first bibles.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind something a little recondite, you could try *herpolhode*. According to Goldstein in *[Classical Mechanics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201657023)*, this word originally meant *snake-like*, from which it was pressed into service with its current [meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herpolhode):-

> A herpolhode is the curve traced out by the endpoint of the angular
>   velocity vector ω of a rigid rotor, a rotating rigid body.

which is indeed wiggly in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I find the word "slithering" can be used as an adjective although it is rare but it certainly is descriptive of "snake-like".